# How do I get a bullet point (•) sent up to my PHP page via NSMutableURLRequest using HTTP POST?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, unicode, sdk

Question about sending up data to my web server using HTTP via my iPhone app... Currently I am sending an HTTP POST request to a page. It looks like this:

```
    NSString *myURLString = @"http://www.myusrl.com/update.php";
   [myRequestString appendString:@"&movietitle=Wall•E"];
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[myRequestString UTF8String] length:[myRequestString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: myURLString]]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

The problem is the bullet point in Wall•E isn't getting sent up. Do I need to percent escape encode it? Or using unicode or set UTF8 somewhere or something? How do I get a bullet point up through to my PHP page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the Unicode value? `&#149;`

Comment: The answer is this. It works perfectly:

    myString = [myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];